# orderBy descending order doesn't work in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I expect to see decesecing order base on `points` work but it doesn't, here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/34/

ng-repeat

```
<ul ng-repeat="friend in user">
    <li ng-repeat="relation in friend.relationship | orderBy:'points':true">    
      {{relation.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

js

```
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
    $scope.user = [{
        'uId': 1,
            'name': 'Joe',
            'relationship': [{
            'uId': 2,
                'name': 'Jeremy',
                'tabs': [{
                'tabId': 1
            }],
                'tasks': [{
                'name': 'Im Jeremy Lin'
            }],
            'points': 50

        }]
    }, {
        'uId': 2,
            'name': 'justin',
            'relationship': [{
            'uId': 3,
                'name': 'Jordan',
                'tabs': [{
                'tabId': 2
            }],
                'tasks': [{
                'name': 'Im Jasmin Jacob'
            }],
            'points': 100

        }]
    }];
})
```

Comment: My guess is that you'll have to write your own filter since it is a nested object.

Comment: You have 2 ng-repeats. Your list has 2 items, each with 1 relationship. When you apply the orderBy to the nested ng-repeat it can only sort the relationship in THAT object. If you want them sorted with respect to each other, then you might need to change the representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example there is only 1 relationship in each of the relationship arrays.  If you add items to those arrays, you can see that they are being sorted correctly.  Here is an update of your fiddle, with extra data for visibility:
http://jsfiddle.net/8Ub6n/

```
$scope.user = [
   {
      'uId':1,
      'name':'Joe',
      'relationship':[
         {
            'uId':2,
            'name':'Jeremy',
            'points':50
         },
         {
            'uId':2,
            'name':'Michael',
            'points':80
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      'uId':2,
      'name':'justin',
      'relationship':[
         {
            'uId':3,
            'name':'Jordan',
            'points':100
         },
         {
            'uId':4,
            'name':'Cameron',
            'points':15
         }
      ]
   }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in nested loop by:

```
<ul ng-repeat="friend in user | orderBy:'relationship':'points':true">
    <li ng-repeat="relation in friend.relationship">    
      {{relation.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here `orderBy:'Array':'expression':reverse`

Comment: <li ng-repeat="friend in user[0].relationship | orderBy:'friend.points':true">{{friend.name}}</li>

what if I want load only for single user? why my above html doesnt work?

Comment: You are trying to sort the single outputted item where you need to sort from array. Your example of sorting from `li` is only possible(like in j.witter's solution) where the array length of `relationship` is more than one.